# How to Render Single Observerble Data in HTML ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, observable, angularfire5

I use Observable to get single object data from the firebase. How do I render this data on HTML? I use this `{{(postObservable2|async)?.subject}}`  but nothing is rendered.
I tried to use AngularFireObject as well but it keeps throwing an error saying that

> firebase datasnapshot type cant assign to the AngularFireObject.

---

> "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4"

```
 this.postObservable = this.firebase.object(`allPosts/${this.postID}`).snapshotChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try subscribing to the observable this way:

```
let yourArray = [];
this.postObservable.subscribe(res => {
  res.map(c => {
    yourArray.push(c);
  })
})
console.log(yourArray);
```

Then in the template use yourArray as ngFor iteratable.